# How to use mongoose getter

Tags: mongoose

I have three fields in my mongoose schema and i want to retrieve only one which will be the average of the other two.

I tried to use mongoose **get** but I dont know if I am using it correctly.

Here is my schema

```
const schema = new Schema({
    totalCarrots: {type: Number},
    numberOfRabbits: {type: Number},
    average: {
        type: Number,
        get: function () {
            const average = this.totalCarrots / this.numberOfRabbits;
            if (average) return Math.ceil(average);
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

I expected **average** to return the calculated value. How can I archive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you don't need `get` here at all actually. Since you're simply looking to generate a dynamic value you could create your own method on the schema's `methods` like this:

```
schema.methods.average = function(){
   const average = this.totalCarrots / this.numberOfRabbits;
   return average ? Math.ceil(average) : null;
}
```

Now you can call this method on an instance of your schema:

```
const doc = new schema({ totalCarrots: 4, numberOfRabbits: 2 })
doc.average() // should return 2
```

`get` is meant to be used on a field that you're actually storing data on and it can modify that field when ever you access it. For example let's say we have a Product model with a `price` field. Our prices are stored as floats, and for what ever reason we want to round the value every time we read it. this would be a good place for a `get` method:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  price: {
    type: Number,
    get: function(value){
      // value arg is referring to the value of a model instance's price
      return Math.round(value)
    }
  }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)

const product = new Product({ price: 15.80 })
product.price // will be 16 because we round the stored value in the get method
```